# Notation for integer linear combinations of the columns from a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I have a question about notation:

Given a matrix $V = [v_0, \ldots, v_n]$ where $v_i$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is there a commonly used notation for the set of all integer linear combinations of the vectors $v_i$? I saw $V\mathbb{Z}$ in one paper but I don't know if that's standard.

Comment: It would be $V \mathbb Z^n$, no?